# What is the proper usage of a pie bird?

Tags: baking, equipment, pie

I have one of those ceramic pie birds that vent steam from a pie while it bakes.  What benefit does using this provide to the end result?  Also, in what types of pies should it be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.piebirds.co.uk/what%20is%20a%20pie%20bird.htm) I found that there are two major benefits to using a pie bird

1. > Prevent the pie from boiling over in
   >   the oven by allowing the steam created
   >   when the fruit filling or other
   >   contents are cooking to escape from
   >   inside the pie
2. > Support the pastry crust in the center
   >   of the pie, so that it did not sag in
   >   the middle

Based on the site it seems that they can be put in any type of pie.

Answer (score 3):

I can add that while you could probably use it with any type of closed pie, you must use one (or a DIY steam vent) when baking a pâté in a crust. Not only will it let the steam escape, you need the big hole to fill the not-yet-set gelatine mix after it has cooled.